# String with new line character ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, xcode6

I'm very new to iPhone programming. actually i've started to write a small app and I'm trying to set a text that contains a new line character to a label.

I have set the label properties to 0 number of lines and selected word wrap.

my text looks like this : `@"ABCD\nEFGH\nIJK"`

instead of printing on a new line on the label it truncates the string after the first new line character. any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you forgot the 'n' after the second '\'. Also, are you sure your view is being framed properly?

Comment: @IanMacDonald Sorry that's a type but it's still the same issue though

Comment: Did you add any constraints to this label. Is auto layout turned on (it is if you haven't turned it off).

Comment: Is your `UILabel` set to a fixed height, or do you allow it to expand with constraints / auto-layout? Or are you managing the frame explicitly in `layoutSubviews`?

Comment: Is the height of the label sufficient to display both lines?

Comment: @WesCossick thanks that sorted out the problem. how silly of me. but then again. I never turned off autolayout option. Won't it automatically fit all the text if I haven't set a height to it? I assumed this since i'm coming from an android bakcground

Comment: No problem! I actually never use auto layout, hopefully somebody else can address that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If auto layout is on, and you don't add any explicit constraints, the system adds them for you. If you look at the size inspector when you haven't added ay constraints yourself, it says this,

> The selected views have no constraints. At build time, explicit left,
>   top, width, and height constraints will be generated for the view.

Having that height constraint is what's probably causing your problem. Add constraints to position the view horizontally and vertically, but don't add any width or height constraints, and that should solve your problem. The system will adjust the width of the label to match your longest line.

Comment: thanks. constraints section mentions the same as you have mentioned. but now that I have increased the height I could see everything on the label, but how do I get it working without having to set a height?

Comment: @Mr.Noob, you shouldn't have to set the height or width, just x and y position. Did you try that?

Comment: yeah I just did. but it still gets truncated half way through

Comment: @Mr.Noob, what gets truncated? Are you still getting just one line? Are you sure that numberOfLines is set to 0?

Comment: Yes it is set 0. following is my code - (void)UpdateUI{
    longString = @"AAAAA\nBBBBB\nCCCCC";
    self.labelIngredients.numberOfLines = 0;
    self.labelIngredients.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.labelIngredients.text = longString;
}

Comment: @Mr.Noob, you shouldn't be setting the autoresizing mask when you use auto layout.

Comment: @Mr.Noob, I tried adding your autoresizing mask line to my app, and (even though you shouldn't do that) it still worked ok. Look at the size inspector for the label. What constraints does it say you have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63192/discussion-between-mr-noob-and-rdelmar).